# Node.JS - Page keeps on running

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I download Windows binaries from node's site and installed on my Windows 7 machine which is installed fine, when I do:

```
node --version
```

It correctly displays its version: `v0.6.7`

Here is the hello world program:

```
// app.js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

And when I do:

```
node app.js
```

I get the response fine:

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

However, when I browser the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, the page **keeps on running** (on status bar it says `waiting for 127.0.0.1...`).

Can anybody help me how to make it to output `Hello World` ?

Comment: I'd try using Fiddler to see what it says is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get with curl:

```
$ curl -vv localhost:8000

* About to connect() to localhost port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:8000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
Hello World
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

nothing wrong with it. Try updating node to the latest stable version (but I don't see how it can help) and be sure any process except node is owning the tcp port 8000.

Comment: In linux (and I would assume in windows also), Node throws an error if it cannot bind into the port.

Comment: `and be sure any process except node is owning the tcp port 8000.` How do i do that ?

Comment: `>curl -vv localhost:8080` gives me `* About to connect() to localhost port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1
.2.3
> Host: localhost:8000
> Accept: */*
>



`

Comment: try double-checking your code for typos, try a different version of nodejs, use a different port (something very unusual like 61331), check for running firewall rules (I don't know where to find this kind of informations under windows), check running software and shut down suspicious ones. You can also try to run node from shell pasting your code and, maybe, inserting some `console.log` statements on every callback you can (like `.listen(12345, function (){ console.log(arguments) })`).

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, this is either one of two things:

1. Node does not recieve the request
2. Node does not respond to the request

To test for either, change your code:

```
// app.js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('got a request');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

Try again.
If node does not get the request, try changing the port to 80 instead of 8000, I had a funny case with firefox blocking non-conventional ports a couple of weeks ago.

Let me know how you go

Comment: The only output i see is `Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000`. There is no `got a request`.

Comment: Also port 80 is occupied by wamp. I need a way to assign another dedicated port to node on which it works fine.

Comment: try 443, thats the one I used, make sure you try http:// and not https:// though. Or temporarily close wamp?

Comment: tried all that, unfortunately still i see page keeps on loading

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Anti Virus or Windows Firewall?

Whichever one you use you might want create a temp exception or disable it for a while just to make sure nothing is getting in the way there.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your listen address to 0.0.0.0. Maybe you're having problems binding to that specific loopback.

Comment: Change ONLY listen address, not both.