# Why can't I see the result on localhost when using Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I just installed node-v.0.7.4.msi on my Win7 64 and wanted to run the following snippet to test it:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  res.end('Hello World\n');

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

But every time I ran it on cmd, it just showed the "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/ ", and I can not open "localhost:1337" in browser to see the "Hello World"(always in loading stage). Does anyone know why? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a problem similar to 
[Node.JS - Page keeps on running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292894/node-js-page-keeps-on-running/9294420#9294420)

My advice on there and here is to make sure AV/Windows firewall is not blocking!

I didn't get a response to that suggestion on the other page.

If you can confirm that it is/isn't the case I have a similar set up that I can test it out on.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Windows 7 and running XAMPP as my localhost server. I changed the port to 3000 instead of 1337. I am also new to Nodejs and tried executing this sample code from the site. I can't explain the exact reason, but it is probably do to a conflict with another process using this port.

I ran the script file in the command line window. I viewed the "Hello World" output string by typing localhost:3000 in Google Chrome.